# Javascript accessing inner function from outside

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following <s>json</s> object

```
{
 ....
 ....
 data: function() {
    var x = 10;
    function isBig() {
        return x>6;
    }
    return x;
 }
}
```

I want the `isBig` to be a function inside data.

When I call `data.isBig` I am getting `undefined` and `data.isBig()` gives me an error saying `isBig` is not a function.

Comment: It wont work that way. No way.

Comment: What you are referring to is not a `json string`. It is a simple javascript object. And that object has a `data` property which is a function which you want invoke.

Comment: Read up on how *"scope"* works in javascript

Comment: JSON is a data transferring format, and it definitely doesn't contain functions ...

Comment: This is the way that function scope works. It is how data is encapsulated to be private. You can expose private data by returning it to the higher scope

Answer (score 3):

First of all, that is not JSON. It is an object.
The way your object is structured currently, `isBig` is only accessible from inside `data`. If you want to access it outside `data`, the simplest way is to make it a property of the outer object:

```
{
    data: function()
    {
        var x = 10;
        return x;
    }
    isBig: function(x)
    {
        return x > 6;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to do that, then an alternative would be this:

```
{
    data: function()
    {
        var x = 10;
        this.isBig = function(x)
        {
            return x > 6;
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

Calling `data()` works normally (returns 10), whereas calling `new data()` returns an object with a property `isBig` which corresponds to the function. This allows you to do this:

```
new myObj.data().isBig()
```

Comment: Is this code tested? I can't get it to work. Have I done something wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/Lv72yrpc/

Comment: @Andrew You forgot the `new` keyword for the second one.

Comment: @stybl if you don't mind me asking... why doesn't my code here work? https://jsfiddle.net/Lv72yrpc/1/

Answer (score 0):

```js
obj = {
 data: function(){
        var x = 10;
    return this.isBig(x);
    },
 isBig: function(x){
           return x > 6;
    }
};
```

And if you want to reproduce the function but useally your better off with an contructor add that point.

```js
f = {
  isSmall: function(){},
  isBig: function(x){
    return x > 6;
  }
};
obj = {
  data: function(){
    var x = 10;
    return this.isBig(x);
  },
  isBig: f.isBig
};
obj.data();
obj.isBig(2);
f.isBig(2);
```